# kafka not assigning replica as leader after all brokers down

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 2 node kafka cluster (replica 0,1) and 3 zookeeper setup.

I tried bring down both kafka nodes (0, 1) for sometime then when I am describing a topic its showing replica 0 as leader as kafka was brought down at the end in replica 0.

```
$ ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo1:2181 --topic test1 --describe
        Topic: test1      PartitionCount:8        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: test1     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 3    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 5    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 6    Leader: 0       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
        Topic: test1     Partition: 7    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
```

Case 1: But when I brings up kafka in replica 1 its still showing same output as above and its not changing it to replica 1 as it up now. And mesage produce and consume is failing for old topics (while for newer topics its working).

Case 2: Now Again I stopped kafka on replica 1 and started on replica 0 then it starts working.

Any there any such tool or any configuration which can assign replica forcefully so that this scenario can be addressed?

Leadership and ISR updating is also huge time.

Kafka & Zookeeper version:

```
kafka_2.11-1.1.0
zookeeper-3.4.10
```

Commands used for stop/start kafka:

```
$systemctl stop kafka.service
$systemctl start kafka.service
```

Comment: Those aren't "replica" numbers, just `broker.id` from the server.properties file. They could be any number. But perhaps you can show the exact commands you used and the Kafka version so someone can reproduce fully?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the commands and versions in question.

Comment: Did you create your own systemctl scripts? Can you also add your kafka server properties to the question?